# Android twitter tweet share with the default tweet box

Tags: android, twitter

I am working in an android application and I want to post tweets to twitter from my android application. I got the a good sample from the link https://github.com/ddewaele/AndroidTwitterSample and I integrated it and it worked successfully. But my requirement is to bring the default tweet box from the original twitter website and post the tweet from it. Is it possible to bring that default tweet box to our application in android.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you just include a WebView with the corresponding Twitter page?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.If I redirect it with the web view,it will go to the twitter site and out of my application.Right? My requirement is to bring that tweet box only in an custom dialog in my android application. IS this possible ?

Comment: In that case, I don't think it's possible in the way you're thinking.  The default twitter dialog is part of a web page.  When a user clicks on the button, they will stay in a web page.  What you can do is try to modify your own dialog to look like the default Twitter one.

Comment: @Arun iam facing same issue any idea of this one help me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the user press button to share tweet you can open a link in WebView(Your Own WebView in your Application) or Default browser.

```
"http://www.twitter.com?status="
```

or to pass any static message,

```
"http://www.twitter.com?status=MyMessageHere"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But After redirect and clicking the tweet button it the twitter it again redirects to the twitter home page. How can we avoid this. After clicking the tweet button and tweeting  it should redirect to the application. How can we handle this.

Comment: After redirecting to this link http://www.twitter.com?status=MyMessageHere and clicking the tweet button, it automatically redirects to the the twitter website home page, rather after clicking it should redirect to the application. Is this possible ?

Comment: may be its possible with using WebViewClient ..there are methods which get called before and after page load..you can check the url and make some logic code..there..

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy   Pls don't use the web view inside ur android application to post tweets...You should integrate the twitter jars into ur application and then post tweets through the application.. There are default classes in the jars by which u can post tweets..

Comment: @Arun iam not useing webview useing edittext in alert dialog get that edit string post to twitter working file. in place of alert any specific tweet dialog available.....

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy You should customize an edit text that should not exceed 140 characters. You can refer this site to get the code http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/